# При использовании find исключить папку на определенном уровне

Tags: linux, bash, find

Есть структура каталога:

```
0fake/a/install/fail.php
0fake/a/install/main/install/fail.php
0fake/a/install/main/fail.php
0fake/a/main/install/me-too.php
0fake/a/main/ok.php
0fake/b/ok.php
0fake/c/ok.php
```

есть команда:
`find 0fake ! -path "*/install/*" -name "*.php"`

как ее поправить что бы она исключила `install` только на втором уровне? что бы был такой результат:

```
0fake/a/main/install/me-too.php
0fake/a/main/ok.php
0fake/b/ok.php
0fake/c/ok.php
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find ./ -name *.php -type f -not -path '*/install/main/install/*'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
find 0fake/  -name '*.php' | grep -vE '^([^/]+/){2}install(/|$)'
```

Результат

```
0fake/a/main/ok.php
0fake/a/main/install/me-too.php
0fake/b/ok.php
0fake/c/ok.php
```

`grep -v` удаляет строки, соответствующие регулярному выражению

`-E` расширенные регулярные выражения

`([^/]+/){2}` два подряд выражения вида `<что-то-без-слэша>/`

`(/|$)` после install либо слэш, либо конец строки